# why GWT Cell widgets are fater?

Tags: gwt

I wanted to know how cell widgets are faster compared normal (old) GWT widgets?

I have gone through the gwt article
[Developer's Guide - Cell Widgets](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html)

It says

> A cell widget renders its user interface as an HTML string, using innerHTML instead of traditional DOM manipulation

Can anyone please explain the above? and How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a normal GWT Grid you have to add each Widget separately, which means the browser can not optimize this in any way. Each widget you add also has its own event handler.
So you will create at least one DOM Element per Widget you add and append it into the grid.

CellWidgets first render all childs into a String which is then added to the DOM, by calling setInnerHTML (the browser can optimize this call and add all childs in a batch) and the event handling is only done once by the CellWidget.